# Pandas: search df column against every list item, pop out matching value from df column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to do a contains replace, and just pop out the matching value from my list.

```
import pandas as pd
mylist = ['australia','hong kong', 'usa']
data = {'col': ['abc company','abc australia xyz','hong kong company']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['col'])
df
```

The output would be:
**df['col']: 'abc company','abc xyz', 'company'**

I've read docs, scoured stackoverflow, looked at regular expressions, list comprehensions, split columns,  etc.

I wish this function would work:

```
df['col'].replace(mylist, "")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex to [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html), and for this to work, join them using '|':

```
df['col'].replace('|'.join(mylist), "", regex=True)
#0    abc company
#1       abc  xyz
#2        company
```

You may want to add [`str.strip()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) to remove unnecessary whitespace